# MacBook Pro 13 will not recognize battery and will not charge after battery replacement

Tags: battery

Did not start my MacBook Pro 13 for 5 weeks. when I tried it was completely dead and would not start up even with charger on it. I ordered a new battery and now it works when pugged into charger but won't charge. Shows battery at 0%. it is like it doesn't recognize the battery and I have reset and still does nothing for the charging aspect. as soon as I pull charging cable out of port it goes dead again

Answer (score 1):

I assume this an old-style (pre-unibody) Mac with a removable/user-replaceable battery pack... If so, contact the seller; you could have been shipped a dud. If it's an aftermarket, non-apple product, you should also visually check to make sure it fits properly, and that all the contacts  are clean, undamaged, and seem to be connecting. As I remember from doing the same thing, some of those 3rd-party packs were less than perfectly machined.

Comment: Sorry I failed to say it is a 2016-17 model. So it is a permanent battery. Does anyone how to test a battery to see if was a good battery that I bought to begin with??

Comment: Did you install the battery yourself? You can get decent information from the System Information app (click on 'Power' in the 'Hardware' section). That will tell you if the battery is connected and recognized by the system, and what its' health and status are.